# At&T Assembly indexing arrays and declaring arrays

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, indexing, declare

How would I go about indexing and declaring arrays in AT&T assembly?

Declaring do I do it like this:

```
array:
    .zero 256
```

Creates array of 256, with values of zero.

Indexing it do I do it like this:

```
movq $array, %r14                //Set array to a register name
                                 //Say that r11 has the number 5 stored
movq (%r14, %r11, 8), %r15       //This will make r15 at index 5 of array
movq %rbx ,%r15                  //This will store value of rbx into r15
```

Is this how I do it? If not, how do I go about creating and indexing arrays in AT&T assembly?

Comment: the language is defined by the tool, what assembler (tool(chain)) are you using?

Comment: Use `lea array(%rip), %r14` or `movl $array, %r14d`.  (Or skip it entirely and use `movq array(,%r11,8), %r15`.)  Never use `movq $symbol_name`; it's never the best way to get a symbol address into a register.  (See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more about when you need an LEA to avoid 32-bit absolute addresses like you're using here.  `movq` still uses a 32-bit immediate.)

Comment: @Peter, I don't understand your last sentence; 48b8 does use a 64-bit immediate.

Comment: @prl: `mov r64,imm64` is movabs, not movq.  AT&T syntax added a different mnemonic for the 64-bit immediate or absolute-address forms of MO: 
 https://web.archive.org/web/20160609221003/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html.  (I didn't mention `movabs` because it's definitely worse than RIP-relative LEA for code-size.)

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly will store the address of the start of the array in `r14`, move the value of the `r11`th element of the array into `r15`, then move the value in `rbx` into `r15`.  It will not move any value into the array.  If you want to move the address of the `r11`th element into `r15` then move the value in `rbx` to the `r11`th element of the array, you would need to use `leaq (%r14, %r11, 8), %r15` to move the address of the `r11`th element of the array into `r15`, then use `movq %rbx, (%r15)` to move the value in `rbx` to the `r11`th element of the array.